# Block unwanted LDAP users from being synchronised with Jira

Tags: ldap, jira

I want to block a set of particular users from being synchronized with Jira, i.e., based on LDAP field values like **gidNumber** and **AccountType**.  Can I exclude those particular users from being synchronized with Jira?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Matt! Finally I've figured out to restrict the certain LDAP users based on **gidNumber** and **AccounType**.

Using the below query in UserObjectFilter did the trick for me-

```
(&(&(objectclass=person)(!(XYZgidnumber=2500)))(!(XYZAccountType=80)))
```